# Cambio de texto en un texto Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js, cli

**Hola**. Estoy tratando de cambiar los siguientes textos en base a la información del usuario, haciendo uso de Vue CLI y Firebase. A continuación les paso mi código:

```js
import Navigation from "@/components/panel/Navigation";
import Userinfo from "@/components/panel/Userinfo";

import firebase from "firebase";
import { db } from "../../../firebase";

export default {
  name: "Main",
  components: {
    Navigation,
    Userinfo
  },
  data (){
    return {
      enterpriseName: null
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var docRef = db.collection("enterprises").doc(user.uid);
    docRef
      .get()
      .then(function(doc) {
        this.enterpriseName = "Hola";
        return this.enterpriseName;
      })
  }
};
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>Nombre de la empresa:</strong>
  {{enterpriseName}}
</p>
```

En lo que respecta al usuario y su información, todo funciona. Sin embargo no logro cambiar el texto **enterpriseName** presente en mi `template`.

Como pueden ver, primero lo cargo con un valor nulo, después al cargar la información del usuario le doy el valor de **Hola**, pero no hace nada.

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que has perdido el contexto de `this`, dentro de `docRef`. Puedes probar a usar una función flecha o `bind()`. Por ejemplo:

```
docRef
 .get()
 .then(function(doc) {
   this.enterpriseName = "Hola";
   return this.enterpriseName;
 }.bind(this))
```